# Composer get progress output of install

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to find a way to get the progress output of a `composer install`. I would like to use this output to show a progress bar to indicate how far a long the command is and communicate this back to the frontend. This will be used for tracking tasks within a deployment.

Currently I don't see a clean way to hook in and get a total step count and current step to display a progress bar. If this even currently possible or is there a workaround to get this data?

Comment: It looks like this may be in the works ([issue 6932](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6932)), but is not available currently.